# How to convert dropdown value to array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

this way i was trying to convert dropdown value to array by jquery but routine is not working.

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

function cboValueToArray(targetid) {
            var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "]");
            var results = [];
            $($target).each(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val !== '') results.push(val);
            });
            alert(results.toString());
            return results;
        }
        alert(cboValueToArray('DropDownList1').toString());
```

this line  `$($target).each()` is causes problem. guide me how to fix this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7h85L9kp/1/)

```
function cboValueToArray(targetid) {
        var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "] option");
        var results = [];
        $target.each(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val !== '') results.push(val);
        });
        alert(results.toString());
        return results;
}
```

Comment: add $ before target  in $target.each

Comment: can u tell me how to attach one onchange event for multiple dropdown and also like to get dropdown id from onchange event. if u know then please help me with sample code. thanks

Comment: Yes. Sure. This is a sample code. Pretty much self explanatory http://jsfiddle.net/e81uezsk/

Comment: i have many dropdown but i want to attach onchange with 2 dropdown in page. how to achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** in jQuery to retrieve value into array

```
var results = $("option", targetid).map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Sample code:

```
var results = $("#DropDownList1 option").map(function () {
    if (this.value != "") { // you can compare value here
        return this.value;
    }
}).get();
console.log(results)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhewxedr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

surly this will help you

```
 $j('.input-box:eq(0) option').each(function() {
        alert($j(this).val()+' :: '+$j(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile explaining why this works and the OP's code doesn't